# Wann wird ein Beruf mit dem unbestimmten Artikel verwendet? Beispiel: "Ich bin Neurobiologe" oder "Ich bin ein Neurobiologe"?

Tags: usage, article

Ich muss gleich vorweg sagen, dass ich selber kein Muttersprachler bin. Jedoch finde ich Konstrukte wie

> Ich bin ein (|Beruf- bzw. Statusbezeichnung|).

etwas unnatürlich und empfinde sie als Anglizismen, etwa wie der bekannte Satz von Kennedy:

> Ich bin ein Berliner.

Jedoch wird mir immer wieder von meinen deutschen Kollegen, die allerdings keine Linguisten sind, geschweige denn Germanisten, gesagt, dass *Ich bin ein Biologe* angeblich "besser" klingt, als *Ich bin Biologe (von Beruf)*. Mir kommt das aber nicht so vor und ich habe die Vermutung, dass es vielleicht für die Kollegen nur etwas besser klingt, weil es dem englischen Satzmuster näher kommt.

Welche Form ist also jetzt zu bevorzugen, wenn man gutes und richtiges Deutsch sprechen möchte?

Comment: In Filmen heißt es jedenfalls immer: "Lassen Sie mich durch, ich bin Arzt!". Nach meinem Gefühl wäre "ein" hier auch deplaziert.

Comment: Wo Kennedy gennant wird, muss man auch erklären dass er recht gehabt hat. Als nicht-Muttersprachler kann ich nicht von selbst reden, aber manche meinen dass "Ich bin ein Berliner" besser als "Ich bin Berliner" klingt, wenn man Metaphorisch redet, und Mitgefühl betont. Soviel ich weiss, meinte zur Zeit kein Muttersprachler dass Kennedy sich als Berliner Pfannkuchen (was übrigens in Berlin nur "Pfannkuchen" heisst) nannte.

Comment: Ich finde, dass der unbestimmte Artikel an der Stelle komisch klingt. Es macht Sinn, wenn man die Zugehörigkeit zu einer Gruppe ausdrücken möchte. *Ich bin ein Mitarbeiter von Petra.* Es gibt noch andere Mitarbeiter, man ist einer von diesen. *Ich bin Student.* Mein beruflicher Status ist Student. Da es um die Statusbezeichnung geht würde ich den unbestimmten Artikel weglassen. Wenn man nämlich mit jemandem redet, der der einzige Mensch in seinem Beruf ist, dann sagt er auch nicht "Ich bin *eine* Königin von England"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Ohne.html#Anchor-Angabe-14210) stellt klar:

> Bei Bezeichnungen des Berufs, der Funktion, [...] einer Person steht kein Artikel, wenn die Zugehörigkeit zu einer Gruppe ausgedrückt wird.
>
> Ebenfalls häufig ohne Artikel stehen diese Bezeichnungen, wenn sie mit einem Verb und "als" verwendet werden.

Man beachte aber die Einschränkung durch den Nebensatz im ersten Abschnitt und das Wort *häufig* im zweiten Absatz. Es wird also schon angedeutet, dass es hier Ausnahmen gibt. Dazu habe ich aber leider keine Quellen gefunden. Möglicherweise bezieht sich dies auch nur auf die "falsche" Verwendung in der Umgangssprache.

Man setzt aber definitiv den unbestimmten Artikel, wenn man die Berufsbezeichung mit einem Attribut versieht, z. B.:

> Er ist ein hervorragender Pilot.

Comment: Gegenbeispiel? Als hervorragender Pilot weiß er, was jetzt zu tun ist.

Answer (score 7):

Beide Varianten sind richtig. Was besser klingt, dürfte wohl vom Kontext abhängen und ist vermutlich auch Geschmacksache.

Wenn jemand mit dem Bundespräsidenten spricht, wäre für mich

> Ich bin Neurobiologe.

die um eine Nuance bessere Wahl.

Wenn ein kleines Kind fragt, was jemand von Beruf ist, wäre folgende Antwort auch absolut in Ordnung:

> Ich bin ein Neurobiologe. Ich erforsche unter anderem das Gehirn von Lebewesen.

Comment: Danke für die schnelle Antwort! Wie wäre es aber mit einem Anschreiben bzw. einer Bewerbung? Welche Form wäre da angemessener?

Comment: Ich persönlich würde an deiner Stelle vermutlich "Ich bin Neurobiologe" schreiben. Es könnte allerdings sein, dass jemand das anders empfindet.

Comment: "Ich bin ein Neurobiologe." - "Ich bin ein Bundespräsident." :D

Comment: "Ich bin ein Neurobiologe" - "Ich bin der Bundespräsident".

Answer (score 5):

Ich kann es leider nur aus dem Bauch beantworten. "Ich bin Biologe" würde ich als Beschreibung meines Berufes empfinden, "Ich bin ein Biologe" als Betonung dessen dass ich Biologe bin.