# What are the syntactical parts of “Ich bin ein Berliner”?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammatical-case

Are these the correct syntactical parts of the sentence “ich bin ein Berliner”?

- *Ich* — subject;
- *bin* — verb;
- *ein Berliner* — direct object.

But if they are, shouldn’t *ein Berliner* have declination, making it *einen Berliner*?
If it is the direct object, should it not be in *Akkusativ*?

… is the verb ***sein*** maybe one of those [exceptions where the Akkusativ does not match the direct object](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28269/difference-between-accusative-and-direct-object)?

Comment: "Ich bin ein Berliner" means you are such a sweet. http://www.alnatura.de/~/media/Images/Content/Kochen%20und%20Geniessen/Warenkunde/Berliner_Pfannkuchen.jpg If you want to say, that you are from Berlin/living in Berlin, you would say "Ich bin Berliner/ Ich komme aus Berlin/ Ich wohne in Berlin"

Comment: @Iris: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ich_bin_ein_Berliner

Comment: @tohuwawohu, just because John F. Kennedy said it, doesn't mean it is correct German. And it should be marked as a quote in the question, if it refers to Kennedy's speech.

Comment: @Iris I am interested in the syntactic interpretation of the sentence, not its meaning. I can change it to `ich bin ein Person` or `... ein Fußballspieler` or `... eine Maschine` or `... ein Pfirsich` or whatever you prefer; that's not important for me. Do you think I should?

Comment: @Iris Why would "Ich bin ein Erfurter" not be correct German? Just because "Berliner" happens to be a pastry, too, doesn't make that wrong. At least it doesn't feel obviously wrong.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu, ja, "Ich bin ein Erfurter ist falsch". Du bist Erfurter, ohne Artikel. Siehe http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Ohne.html#Anchor-Angabe-14210

Comment: @ANeves, if you are talking about your job or your origin, no article is used in German. So there is a grammatical difference between "Ich bin eine Maschine" and "Ich bin Maschinist".

Comment: Siehe auch: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/wann-wird-ein-beruf-mit-dem-unbestimmten-artikel-verwendet-beispiel-ich-bin-n

Comment: @Iris Magst Du dann bitte den verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel korrigieren? Der widerspricht Dir und Canoo, und damit auch der Antwort in der anderen Frage. "Der Satz ist also korrekt und wurde auch vor der Rede entsprechend geprüft." - http://bit.ly/1Y8RnBs

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu, das ist lustig, weil der Wikiartikel auch auf canoo verweist: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/ArtIndef.html Nur hier wird argumentiert, dass Berliner eine Klasse sei.

Comment: nice :D Die Interpretation halte ich für stichhaltig, denn zweifelsohne war die Intention von Kennedy, auszudrücken, dass er einer von vielen sei. Und das "viele" ist dann die Klasse. Abseits davon spricht der Artikel davon, die Rede sei geprüft worden.

Comment: I will not edit "ein Berliner". Both the forms with and without article seem to be correct (see [german.SE #1](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23719/sind-sie-ingenieur-should-be-sind-sie-ein-ingenieur) and [german.SE #2](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/wann-wird-ein-beruf-mit-dem-unbestimmten-artikel-verwendet-beispiel-ich-bin-n)), and I need an article for my question to make sense.

Comment: @Iris: Ich bin Grazer. However, if I want to say that this describes the kind of person I am, rather than just giving my place of origin, I will say "Ich bin ein Grazer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake. "ein Berliner" here is no *direct object*, it is an *attribute*.

The difference is that a state verb (bleiben, heißen, sein, werden, genannt werden, gerufen werden) introduces an **attribute**, while other verbs introduce the **direct object**. Since it is certain (because of the state verb) that the *attribute* refers to the same person/thing as the subject, it uses the same declination as the subject, which is the *Nominative* instead of the *Accusative*.

> Ich bin *ein Berliner*. (attribute)
>
> Ich sehe *einen Berliner*. (object)

An *attribute* can be a noun (der attributive Name), or an adjective (das attributive Adjektiv) :

> Ich bin ein Berliner. (name)
>
> Ich bin froh. (adjective)

An example of the use of the state verb (example with blieben) :

> Ich bleibe ich.
>
> Ich bleibe ein Berliner.

And examples using regular verbs that call for direct object:

> Ich sehe mich.
>
> Ich sehe einen Berliner.

Comment: This answer is wrong (or at least heavily misleading). *Berliner* here is exactly not *attributiv*, but *prädikativ* (the exact opposite). *Berliner* is the *Subjektsprädikativ* to "ich" - like in "Ich bin ein Bäcker*. Some grammars define this as "nominative object".

Answer (score 22):

*ein Berliner* is in *Nominativ* since it is a *Gleichsetzungsnominativ* (predicate noun).

You don’t ask

> **Wen oder was** bin ich?

but instead you do ask

> **Wer oder was** bin ich?

Have a look at [*Nominativ* on the German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominativ)

*Gleichsetzungsnominativ* can follow the verbs *sein, werden, heißen, scheinen (zu sein), bleiben, gelten (als), (sich) fühlen (als), (sich) dünken (als), (sich) erweisen (als), (sich) entpuppen (als), sich glauben (als)*

Comment: ... or *ich bin wer oder was*, if you want to stick to the word order of the original sentence.

Comment: Auf eine Frage im Deutschunterricht "Gleichsetzungsnominativ" zu antworten bringt Pluspunkte. ;-) Wir haben ihn glaube ich auch noch Prädikativ genannt. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Praedikativ

Comment: Der Gleichsetzungsnominativ ist ein Prädikativ, nicht jedes Prädikativ aber ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ.

Comment: I wrongly upvoted this answer. You cannot give as solution for a lerner the questions that you pose, when *you*, German-speaker, ask when you want to know the case. A German learner just doesn't know which question should be posed. E.g. suppose I don't know that *zuhören* goes with dative: why should I know that I have to ask *Wem höre ich zu?* if I don't know that *zuhören* goes with dative, I could just as well have asked *wen höre ich zu?*.

Comment: @RalleKalle 1) Is my syntactic analysis otherwise correct? 2) In `Gleichsetzungsnominativ can follow the verbs`, does "can" mean that it's possible to use *sein* (etc.) without a predicate noun, which would then perhaps take something in *Akkusativ* instead of *Nominativ*?

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not correct. The *direct object* refers to grammar of other languages. In German there is no such thing.

On the other hand, you are right in wondering why *Berliner* is not in accusative. The solution to the analysis **inside the German grammar** would be that *sein* (just as *heißen*, usw.) allows two (pro)nouns in nominative.

> *Ich* — subject;
>      *bin* — verb;
>      *ein Berliner* — noun in nominative ([predicative noun](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gleichsetzungsnominativ)).

Answer (score 1):

If the item comes after a state verb, it will always be a nominative and not an accusative. This is not particular to German but applies in Latin, Ancient Greek and all other languages that use declension.