# Why is "sein" not transitive?

Tags: verb

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb): "A transitive verb is a verb that accepts one or more objects."

*Sein* accepts objects. *Das ist ein **Buch***.

Comment: Also Wikipedia: 'In der traditionellen Schulgrammatik wird Transitivität über die Eigenschaft eines Verbs, den Kasus Akkusativ zu regieren, definiert. Ein Verb ist demnach transitiv (dann auch „zielendes“ Verb genannt), wenn einer seiner Mitspieler den Kasus Akkusativ trägt.' Does it matter whether some grammar calls a verb transitive or not?

Comment: I took he pleasure to check which language version of Wikipedia would actually make such an oversimplified statement (which isn't even true in English). I could find none.

Comment: @tofro https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb

Comment: Quite similar [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/30237), which could even qualify as duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on topic for the site, since it's about a English Wikipedia article which isn't talking specifically about German. Perhaps the discussion should more properly be on Wikipedia.

Comment: @RDBury well, to be precise, the wiki article seems to be talking specifically about English without saying so.

Comment: @tofro: Yes, that seems to be the case with many of the grammar articles in the English Wikipedia. As a learner I've found the phenomenon rather frustrating, not to mention unscientific.

Answer (score 5):

A transitive verb in German requires an object in the accusative case.

However, "ein Buch" is not an accusative object but a *[Gleichsetzungnominativ](https://learngerman.dw.com/de/gleichsetzungsnominativ/gr-40577986)*, i. e. it's an additional component part of the sentence in the nominative.

Although the accusative and the nominative form are both "ein Buch" you cannot ask "Wen oder was ist das?", which asks for the accusative. This is totally wrong.  But you can ask for a nominative "Wer oder was ist das?" and you will get the answer "ein Buch".

Try to construct an example where the accusative object is clearly distinct from the nominative object. Take, for example, "einen Tisch" (accusative case). You cannot say "Das ist einen Tisch", which clearly shows that "sein" is not transitive.

Comment: I may be completely on the wrong track here, but doesn't the "sein" function as a [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)) in this case? Could that mean that, because the verb is performing a different function, the "normal" attributes of the verb like transitive / intransitive don't really come into play? Similar to auxiliary verbs.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Yes, I think you might be right. A sentence like from the question can be found [here](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/381) under "Syntaktische Eigenschaften" called "Nominalphrase im Nominativ". My main point though is that a verb that doesn't take an accusative object can't be transitive in the first place. (My premise was that OP seems to think that "ein Buch" is accusative.) So both ways of reasoning give the same result I guess.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck (1) Yes, *sein* in the example is a copula verb. In Germanic linguistics copulas are usually introduced as a separate category from full verbs and auxiliary verbs. The transitive/intransitive distinction, however, can be applied to them. If you do that, you will see that in German they are actually intransitive as they do not take an accusative object. (There are languages with transitive copulas.) (2) There is no disagreement between your observation and the answer. The presence of a "Gleichsetzungsnominativ" in the example is precisely a feature of *sein* being a copula.

Comment: I would not call it a *nominative object*, by the way. It's precisely *not* an object, so this language might be slightly confusing. Technically, *ein Buch* in the example could be described as a nominative *complement*, although (as indicated in the answer) this particular use of that complement is referred to in various more specific ways in grammars of German (*Gleichsetzungsnominativ*, also: *Nominalergänzung, prädikativer Nominativ, Prädikatsnomen, Prädikativkomplement*, ...).

Comment: @johnl I agree. This might be oversimplified. I tried to rephrase the answer to avoid any confusion.

Comment: My understanding is *sein*, like the English "to be", is a "copulative verb", though perhaps "predicate verb" would be more accurate. A predicate can be an adjective or a noun phrase. In the case of a noun you can call is a "predicate object", these usually take the objective case in English and the nominative case in German (one instance where English and German don't agree on cases). German and English don't really agree on what's considered a transitive verb (much to the consternation of learners). Perhaps a better term for German would be "accusative verb".

Answer (score 3):

If you're unsure about the case being Akkusativ, there's another test:

If "sein" were a transitive verb, it should be possible to construct a passive-voice version of that sentence.

- The original accusative object becomes the subject.
- The original subject gets converted into a "von" or "durch" phrase.
- The verb gets replaced by a phrase with "werden" and the past participle (Partizip Perfekt).

E.g. "Ich fahre das Auto" becomes "Das Auto wird von mir gefahren".

But, trying to convert "Das ist ein Buch" along the rules simply gives nonsense: "Ein Buch wird davon gewesen".

In English, it's the same: you can't convert a sentence "This is a book" with the verb "to be" into passive voice: "A book is been by this" is as much nonsense as the German counterpart.